# ASP.NET MVC Tutorials using SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How can I use SQLServer (instead of SQL Express) as my database?

I'm trying to go thru the [ContactManager](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-26-cs.aspx) tutorial, but I can't seem to get it to use SQLServer - when I pick SQLServer from the "Add New Item" dialog, I get an error telling me that SQL Express isn't installed.

I know I must be missing something basic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most tutorials on the ASP.NET site are written in such a way, that you don't have to buy any software to do them. They use Visual Studio Express and SQL Express in their examples.

However, You can still follow along with the tutorial. Just make a few adjustments. Go to the Server Explorer to create a Connection to your SQL Server, and create the database and tables.

Then when it comes to the step of creating the EntityDataModel, create a new connection to the database you just created.

Answer (score 0):

Only SQL Express can attach your database at runtime. If you have a non express version of SQL Server you will need to create the SQL Server using SSMS. If you want the file to physically live in app_data then when asked where to put the database file and the ldf indicate the app_data folder. Once you have created it, it is easy enough to simply add it as an exsisting item, although it can't be checked into source safe without creating obvious issues. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a full-fledged instance of SQL Server, you don't need to use the "Add New Item" dialog at all.  Rather, connect to your SQL Server instance (via Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio), and create the new database there.